# A concise solution to "find the range of $x$ in $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)>0$ where $a<b<c$".

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, alternative-proof

> Find the range of $x$ in $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)>0$ where $a<b<c$.

Graphically, this is obvious; it's the "bump" between $a$ and $b$, and $c$ to $\infty$ (and beyond!).

Numerically, it's a bit tedious but gets the job done; I test all combinations of $x$ that are larger/smaller than $a$/$b$/$c$.

Algebraically, it's about as tedious as numerically; I rigorously solve the inequality and end up with a ton of little inequalities, then I throw out all the invalid and redundant inequalities and end up with $a<x<b$ and $c<x$.

**Is there a short and sweet algebraic solution to this inequality?**

Comment: If $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) > 0$, then either one of the three multiplicands is positive, or all three multiplicands are positive. Given $a < b < c$, what $x$-values do these two scenarios correspond with?

Comment: There's an easy asymptotic solution-- just note that the function goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ and to $\infty$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$. It has no double roots so it changes sign every time you go past a root (travelling from left to right).

Comment: @AlexWertheim -- I see what you're getting at. However, can you elaborate a bit more? I've gotten to where $x-a$ is always positive and $x-b$ and $x-c$ must be either both positive or negative.

Comment: If $x < a$, then each of $(x-a), (x-b), (x-c)$ are negative, and thus so is their product. If $a < x < b$, then $(x-a)$ is positive, but $(x-b), (x-c)$ are negative, so the product of all three is positive. Try the remaining cases out to see if you understand.

Comment: @AlexWertheim -- Ah, yes. Got it. I expected a more rigorous solution, but I suppose that'll do. Thanks! **Update:** Isn't your hint essentially dxiv's solution?

Comment: Happy to help, though there's nothing about my proposed solution which is not rigorous. Perhaps you mean a solution which doesn't involve casework - in this case, Vik78's nice comment is what you want, I think. Yes, my suggestion and dxiv's solution are (functionally) the same.

Comment: @AlexWertheim -- After mentioning rigorousness, I thought about if there were many factors (or, multiplicands, as you say). Wouldn't your/dxiv's method become tedious (and inelegant)?

Comment: Whether a method is tedious (i.e. comprised of many small steps) is independent of whether it is rigorous (i.e. does not contain gaps or ''handwaving'', as some might say). That said, the method I propose (and dxiv uses) can be easily generalized to make short work of the problem, if one actually understand the method. If your roots are $a_{1} < a_{2} < \cdots < a_{n}$ for $n$ (say) odd, then you can show that your product is positive for $a_{i} < x < a_{i+1}$ for each $i$ odd. (The sign of the product is maintained when pairs of two multiplicands change sign!)

Comment: @AlexWertheim -- Can I also can prove a similar theorem with even $n$, and then I'm all set to quickly find the answer to such problems?

Comment: Yes, you can. It would be a good exercise to both formulate and justify said similar statement. To do so and understand what changes when $n$ is even would demonstrate a good understanding of the problem, I think. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll go try it out later. In case I get stuck on the proof, I'll be back on Math.SE in no time! `:)`

Comment: You can also use my method for a polynomial p(x) whose roots are $n$ (not necessarily distinct) real numbers. If the degree of $p$ is even it goes to $\infty$ as $x$ goes to $\pm \infty$; if the degree is odd it goes to $\pm \infty$ as $x$ goes to $\pm \infty$, respectively. The sign of $p$ changes when you pass a root $a$ iff $a$ has odd multiplicity.

Comment: You also have to account for the sign of the leading coeffcient. I'll probably post an answer soon.

Comment: Isn't the leading coefficient always $+1$ in $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\cdots$?

Comment: I'm talking about a general polynomial, written as a product of linear factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
x & (-\infty,a) & (a,b) & (b,c) & (c,\infty) \\
\hline
\operatorname{sgn}(x-a) & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 \\
\operatorname{sgn}(x-b) & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 \\
\operatorname{sgn}(x-c) & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 \\
\hline
\operatorname{sgn}(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) & -1 & +1& -1 & +1 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I like this, but I feel like this method could become tedious if you had many more factors. 3 is quick and easy, but not 30. Is this the best universal way of solving similar problems?

Comment: Something like the above is a rather safe way to keep track of how factors change signs and interact. Of course, for $3$ factors you could essentially "visualize" it without necessarily writing it down. I would argue that for $30$ factors it becomes even *more* critical to organize everything in a manageable form, even if it may not always be the prettiest.

Comment: Apparently, there _is_ a short way to solving larger problems like this. See @AlexWetheim's latest comments. However, if I ever forget those theorems (and I likely will in a few weeks `:)`), I'd be using your method to find the answer.

Comment: @SirJony There are shortcuts *sometimes*, but you must be careful to recognize *when* you can take them. Compare for example your current question $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) \gt 0$ to $(x-a)(x-b)^2(x-c) \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that concern would show up only when $a<b<c<\cdots$ isn't true (i.e. $a\leq b\leq c\leq \cdots$), so it would be safe to use those theorems mentioned, correct?

Comment: @SirJony No, point in my previous example is that $x=b$ is a zero where the function does *not* change sign.

Comment: Oh, my apologies! I didn't see the $\geq 0$. But, assuming that were $> 0$ (as I thought), I'd be correct in my statement?

Comment: @SirJony Assuming you refer to @AlexWertheim's `the sign of the product is maintained when pairs of two multiplicands change sign` that's correct of course. Point here was that a multiplicand does not necessarily change sign at each one of its roots.

Answer (score 1):

Any $x$ satisfying your inequality will be such that $x\neq a,b,c$, so the LHS of the inequality will be a product of three nonzero reals. Since their product is positive, this means the number of negative reals (among those three) must be even.

For $0$ negative reals, you're in $x>c$.

For $2$ negative reals, you're in $a<x<b$.